# Links Are Showing Of Next Slide In A Slider. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, gallery

I am working on a slider and all things is working fine but the problem is that it is showing link on next slide in current slide. How to fix it? You can see live DEMO at **http://jsfiddle.net/gwbqvqjs/**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[    
/* general variables */
var galleryId = 'gallery'; /* change this to the ID of the gallery list */
var gallery; /* this will be the object reference to the list later on */
var galleryImages; /* array that will hold all child elements of the list */
var currentImage; /* keeps track of which image should currently be showing */
var previousImage;
var preInitTimer;
preInit();
/* functions */
function preInit() {
    /* an inspired kludge that - in most cases - manages to initially hide the image gallery list
       before even onload is triggered (at which point it's normally too late, and the whole list already
       appeared to the user before being remolded) */
    if ((document.getElementById)&&(gallery=document.getElementById(galleryId))) {
        gallery.style.visibility = "hidden";
        if (typeof preInitTimer != 'undefined') clearTimeout(preInitTimer); /* thanks to Steve Clay http://mrclay.org/ for this small Opera fix */
    } else {
        preInitTimer = setTimeout("preInit()",2);
    }
}
function fader(imageNumber,opacity) {
    /* helper function to deal specifically with images and the cross-browser differences in opacity handling */
    var obj=galleryImages[imageNumber];
    if (obj.style) {
        if (obj.style.MozOpacity!=null) {  
            /* Mozilla's pre-CSS3 proprietary rule */
            obj.style.MozOpacity = (opacity/100) - 0;
        } else if (obj.style.opacity!=null) {
            /* CSS3 compatible */
            obj.style.opacity = (opacity/100) - 0;
        } else if (obj.style.filter!=null) {
            /* IE's proprietary filter */
            obj.style.filter = "alpha(opacity="+opacity+")";
        }
    }
}
function fadeInit() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        preInit(); /* shouldn't be necessary, but IE can sometimes get ahead of itself and trigger fadeInit first */
        galleryImages = new Array;
        var node = gallery.firstChild;
        /* instead of using childNodes (which also gets empty nodes and messes up the script later)
        we do it the old-fashioned way and loop through the first child and its siblings */
        while (node) {
            if (node.nodeType==1) {
                galleryImages.push(node);
            }
            node = node.nextSibling;
        }
        for(i=0;i<galleryImages.length;i++) {
            /* loop through all these child nodes and set up their styles */
            galleryImages[i].style.position='absolute';
            galleryImages[i].style.top=0;
            galleryImages[i].style.zIndex=0;
            /* set their opacity to transparent */
            fader(i,0);
        }
        /* make the list visible again */
        gallery.style.visibility = 'visible';
        /* initialise a few parameters to get the cycle going */
        currentImage=0;
        previousImage=galleryImages.length-1;
        opacity=100;
        fader(currentImage,100);
        /* start the whole crossfade process after a second's pause */
        window.setTimeout("crossfade(100)", 1000);
    }
}
function crossfade(opacity) {
        if (opacity <= 100) {
            /* current image not faded up fully yet...so increase its opacity */
            fader(currentImage,opacity);
            /* fader(previousImage,100-opacity); */
            opacity += 5;
            window.setTimeout("crossfade("+opacity+")", 10);
        } else {
            /* make the previous image - which is now covered by the current one fully - transparent */
            fader(previousImage,0);
            /* current image is now previous image, as we advance in the list of images */
            previousImage=currentImage;
            currentImage+=1;
            if (currentImage>=galleryImages.length) {
                /* start over from first image if we cycled through all images in the list */
                currentImage=0;
            }
            /* make sure the current image is on top of the previous one */
            galleryImages[previousImage].style.zIndex = 0;
            galleryImages[currentImage].style.zIndex = 100;
            /* and start the crossfade after a second's pause */
            opacity=0;
            window.setTimeout("crossfade("+opacity+")", 5000);
        }

}
/* initialise fader by hiding image object first */
addEvent(window,'load',fadeInit)
/* 3rd party helper functions */
/* addEvent handler for IE and other browsers */
function addEvent(elm, evType, fn, useCapture) 
// addEvent and removeEvent
// cross-browser event handling for IE5+,  NS6 and Mozilla
// By Scott Andrew
{
 if (elm.addEventListener){
   elm.addEventListener(evType, fn, useCapture);
   return true;
 } else if (elm.attachEvent){
   var r = elm.attachEvent("on"+evType, fn);
   return r;
 }
} 
//]]>
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#slider {max-height:700px;background: url(&quot;https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-LLFEz-EyGbk/UyV9SbGPuhI/AAAAAAAAMgY/JNqf8X11dbk/s220/slider-loader.gif&quot;) #2e2e2e no-repeat 50% 50%;}
#gallery {padding:0;position:relative;margin:0 auto;max-width:1920px;}
#gallery li {list-style-type:none;width:100%;display:block;}
.gallery_img img {max-width:100%;}
.gallery_text {width:1000px;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;margin-left:-500px;margin-top:-110px;}
.gallery_text h2 {padding:0;line-height:70px;font-size:50px;font-weight:inherit;color:#fff;}
.gallery_text p {margin:20px 0;line-height:24px;font-size:20px;color:#ffee66;}
.gallery_text a {background:#77aa00;display:inline-block;padding:20px 70px;font-size:18px;font-weight:700;text-transform:uppercase;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;}
.gallery_text a:hover {background:#fff;color:#000;}
</style>
<div class='clear'/>
<div id='slider'>
<ul id='gallery'>
<li style='position:relative!important;'>
<div class='gallery_img'><img alt='Google' src='https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Nh50j1-Bqws/UyV9Pv_wd3I/AAAAAAAAMf8/nsYUnwm35Gs/s1920/slide_1.jpg' title='Google'/></div>
<div class='gallery_text'><h2>Google</h2><p>Google is an American multinational corporation specializing in Internet-related services and products. These include online advertising technologies, search, cloud computing, and software. Most of its profits are derived from AdWords.</p><a href='http://www.google.com'>Open Google</a></div>
</li>
<li>
<div class='gallery_img'><img alt='Bing' src='https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-eGrPYj9dz1c/UyV9QgDIh5I/AAAAAAAAMgM/mlcDdyufQJs/s1920/slide_2.jpg' title='Bing'/></div>
<div class='gallery_text'><h2>Bing</h2><p>Bing is a search engine that brings together the best of search and people in your social networks to help you spend less time searching and more time doing.</p><a href='http://www.bing.com'>Open Bing</a></div>
</li>
<li>
<div class='gallery_img'><img alt='Yahoo' src='https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-L_s8vxgupPY/UyV9RKToZeI/AAAAAAAAMgQ/TWs-wy7lbrk/s1920/slide_3.jpg' title='Yahoo'/></div>
<div class='gallery_text'><h2>Yahoo</h2><p>Yahoo! Inc. is an American multinational Internet corporation headquartered in Sunnyvale, California.</p><a href='http://www.yahoo.com'>Open Yahoo</a></div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class='clear'/>
```

When you will move your mouse at link then you will see that the link is showing of next slide. Here I am also adding the codes to view it here too.

Comment: Have a look at your `li`'s html while they slide, `z-index` and `opacity` are out of sync. Current image's `z-index` is 100 its `opacity` is 0, previous image's `z-index` is 0, its `opacity` = 1

Comment: @artm Yes, this is it where I am confused. Tried many ways but not able to fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/gwbqvqjs/2/

Changing these lines:

```
galleryImages[previousImage].style.zIndex = 0;
galleryImages[currentImage].style.zIndex = 100;
```

to this:

```
galleryImages[previousImage].style.zIndex = 100;
galleryImages[(currentImage + 1) % galleryImages.length].style.zIndex = 0;
```

and changing other code to:

```
opacity=0;
window.setTimeout(function() {
    galleryImages[previousImage].style.zIndex = 0;
    galleryImages[previousImage].style.opacity = 0;
    crossfade(opacity);
}, 5000);
```

fixes it. Your code is more complicated than it needs to be, swapping currentImage with previousImage `previousImage=currentImage;` etc. make it hard to see what's going on. Try to simplify it.

Comment: You got me and solved me. If you have any easy coding of these features then I will welcome that...

Comment: @MuhammadHassan OK, I'll try to have a look at it sometime, remind me if I dont.

Comment: See what I tried... Is this code acceptable...??? DEMO at: **http://jsfiddle.net/yyathnom/**

Comment: @MuhammadHassan There's really no definition of `acceptable`, depends on the person, but you have 2 functions instead of 4-5, without recursive calls, so that's an improvement. Also you don't have `previous=next`, so that helps as well. It looks much better though, so well done. I'll have a look at it later in more detail to see if it can be shortened further but looks much better as it is.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I hate JQuery but I know that JQuery can do all the features in less coding but I want to make a full feature slider without JQuery. I also don't want to use CSS3 that you know better that is not compatible with some old browser. So my next target is to add some navigation button in this code so your help will be welcomed...

Answer (score 0):

use this.. :) `<a>`position will change but link jumping perfectlly.

```html
<a style="position:absolute; margin-left:-50%; top:318px;" href='http://www.google.com'>Open Google</a>
<a style="position:absolute; margin-left:-15%; top:318px;" href='http://www.bing.com'>Open Bing</a>
<a style="position:absolute; margin-left:24%; top:318px;" href='http://www.yahoo.com'>Open Yahoo</a>
```

Good Luck!